# Getting Messages from Inbox

Tags: javascript, multithreading, facebook-javascript-sdk, message, inbox

I have a question about the Graph API.

I use Javascript for the API and make a little test website ,where you can log in ,look for new messages and write a new status.

My problem is that I can't get the messages or the thread.

```
FB.api('/me/inbox',function(response) {  alert(response.id); } ); don't work.
```

Have somebody an example for getting the messages in the inbox??

Thanks

Comment: What's not working exactly, what Does `console.log(response)` say?

Comment: Is there a url we can look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`/me/inbox` request](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/inbox) requires that you have the `read_mailbox` permission granted.

Once you've got that, the `/me/inbox` request will return an array of [`Thread`'s](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/), which will look something like this;

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1126884978255", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Someone's Name", 
        "id": "34723472"
      }, 
      "to": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Someone's Name", 
            "id": "34723472"
          }, 
          {
            "name": "Matt Lunn", 
            "id": "560914724"
          }
        ]
      }, 
      "message": "Testing the one-ness.", 
      "updated_time": "2012-01-31T12:13:00+0000", 
      "unread": 0, 
      "unseen": 0, 
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "1126884978255_6769", 
            "from": {
              "name": "Someone's Name", 
              "id": "34723472"
            }, 
            "message": "£140!?", 
            "created_time": "2012-01-31T11:33:15+0000"
          },
          {
            "id": "1126884978255_6771", 
            "from": {
              "name": "Matt Lunn", 
              "id": "560914724"
            }, 
            "message": "^^ month in advance as well", 
            "created_time": "2012-01-31T11:33:26+0000"
          }
        ]
      }, 
      "type": "thread"
    }
  ], 
  "summary": {
    "unseen_count": 0, 
    "unread_count": 21, 
    "updated_time": "2012-01-31T13:19:31+0000"
  }
}
```

So depending which `ID`  you're after, you'll have to do;

```
for (var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++) {
    var thread = response.data[i];

    for (var j=0;j<thread.comments.data.length;j++) {
        var comment = thread.comments.data[j];

        console.log(comment.message);
    }
}
```

Hopefully you get the idea...

Comment: Why you write thread.comments?? In the Thread object isn't a member with then name comments.I think you mean messages ?

Comment: So I wrote alert(thread.message) and become the message but the object Thread don't contain this member ??!! Why that ?

Comment: @StanIAm: It seems the response received does not match the documentation. Go on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/inbox and you can see the response being returned. An extract of the response I saw is what is included in my answer.

Comment: Thanks it works now ,it have to be : var comment = thread.comments.data[j] ,because the object are under "data" ,so now it works well :D